# Calculate modulo of a large number represented as a string

Tags: c++, modulus, largenumber

Suppose I have a large number (around 10^5 digits) and I have to calculate num % a where a is less than 10^9 i.e. it is in the int range of C++. There's this code :-

```
int res = 0;

//num contains the large number stored as a string
for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
    res = (res*10 + (int)num[i] - '0') % a; 
    }

return res;
```

I know that this solution uses modular arithmetic but I don't get why we are multiplying *res* by 10 at every iteration.

Suppose I have a number 32471.
According to this code first step will be
`(0 * 10 + 3) % a`

Why this 10? Should it not be
`(0 % a + (3 * 10^4) % a) % a`  and so on, according to modular arithmetic?

Can someone explain how we arrived at this?

Comment: `*10` performed 4 times accumulates to 10^4, doesn't it?

Comment: also this will still overflow when res gets big enough

Comment: ...and it would require you to know in advance how many digits there are _after_ the current position, while the original algorithm accumulates appropriate number of `*10` just by iterating till the end of the digits' sequence.

Comment: @Yamahari `res` won't get big enough. The largest possible intermediate result is `10*a + 9`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik "a is less than 10^9" no further specification, considering `res` is an int this can overflow for every a starting at 214748364 if my math is correct x)

Answer (score 0):

I'll be using the following formulas to elaborate your example

A. **[a + b] % n = [(a % n) + (b % n)] % n**

B. **[a * b] % n = [(a % n) * (b % n)] % n**

C. **[a % n] % n = a % n**

So using your example **32471 % a**:

1. At first you have `0 + 3 % a` which is equal to `3 % a`
2. Then you end up doing `((3 % a) * 10 + 2) % a`. We can express the following:

*Original statement*

**((3 % a) * 10 + 2) % a**

*Using formula **A***

**= (((3 % a) * 10) % a + 2 % a) %a**

*Using formula **B***

**= (((3 % a) % a * 10 % a) % a + 2 % a) %a**

*Using formula **C***

**= (((3 % a * 10 % a) % a + 2 % a) %a**

*Using formula **B***

**= ((30 % a + 2 % a) %a**

*Using formula **A***

**= 32 % a**

3. So now you have `((32 % a) * 10 + 4) % a` which is, using the similar logic expressed above, equal to `324 % a`
4. And then `((324 % a) * 10 + 7) % a` which is equal to `3247 % a`

And finally you would end up with `((3247 % a) * 10 + 1) % a` which is equal to `32471 % a`